# ocr and image preprocessing techniques

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr

Hi all I have a collection of images that are similar to photos of car registration plates.

I am wondering how to pre process the image before sending it to an OCR engine to determine the text.

I would like to eventually be able to crop the input on only the white content of the registration plate.

The actual image would look something like this:

[image: input]

and should end up something like this (color depth not important)
[image: ouput]

Thank for any help.
Regards,
Bob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Segment the image (take a look at [this](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~pff/segment/)).
- Classify segments using a gray scale threshold (since you're just looking for white).
- Crop the image by using the white segment bounding box (or bounding boxes, if it breaks down in more than one segment). *This is probably not going to work for white cars* - but it should not be too difficult to establish a few rules for this case.
- Take a look at [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) to extract the text.

Comment: I'm already looking at tesseract and it works great.. once the image processing is working well :)

Comment: Just ask if you have any trouble :)

Comment: hi @VitorBraga I have use the segment the image link code but when ever I tried to use the segment command with `./segment 0.5 500 20 js.jpeg rs.jpeg` in terminal on os x i got one error called `terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6`. Will you help me out of it ? Can you give me some information regarding where I am wrong? Please help me out of this problem :)

Comment: I have almost same kind of problem see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13247914/1132951) question where I stuck and to resolve it what I have tried so far. And also the answer which is given by me and accepted but not properly working :(